# C++ How to fix error LNK2001: unresolved external "__imp_vprintf" when linking Libraries

Tags: c++, lnk2001

I'm encountering a problem with linking my libraries correctly, and I have already tried various solutions found in multiple threads and websites. However, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in solving this problem quickly.

The error I am facing is as follows:

`Error LNK2001 Unresolved external Symbol "__imp__vprintf". NinjaPlatformer PathToProgram\Platformer\NinjaPlatformer\Box2D.lib(b2Settings.obj)`

Here are my current settings:

- Include directories: `$(SolutionDir)deps/include/;$(SolutionDir);$(IncludePath)`
- Library directories: `$(SolutionDir)deps/lib/Release/;$(SolutionDir)Release/bin/;$(LibraryPath)`
- Additional dependencies: `SDL2.lib;SDL2_mixer.lib;SDL2_ttf.lib;SDL2main.lib;opengl32.lib;glew32.lib;Bengine.lib;Box2D.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Platformer
   Debug
      bin
      some stuff...
   Release
      bin
      some stuff...
   Bengine (My GameEngine)
      some stuff...
   deps
      include
         Box2D, GL, glm, SDL, TTF
      lib
         Debug / Release:
            The libs, I mentioned at the top of the question
   NinjaPlatformer (Main Program)
      some files for main program
```

I have also included the error log for reference: [Error Log](http://pastebin.com/UkUD7Bbu) (in German)

Comment: Try the line `#undef main` in front of your `int main` function. SDL2 has can have problems with VS2015. Here's some other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247992/how-to-fix-unresolved-externals-of-sdl-2-0-3-on-visual-studio-2015-preview, and http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/setting-up-sdl2-with-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32418900/12711 for some info that might help.  You might need to rebuild your libraries with VS 2015.

Comment: Can you please include a dump to what `%(AdditionalDependencies)` resolves to? Because it looks like one of the CRT dependencies is missing or mismatching between your project and `Box2D.lib`

Comment: I guess `%(AdditinalDependencies)` resolves to kernel32.lib
_user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib_

Comment: I'm a bit further... Now my Error message is: 

Error LNK2001 Unresoved external symbol ""public: void __thiscall Box::init(class b2World *,struct glm::detail::tvec2<float,0>,struct glm::detail::tvec2<float,0>,struct Bengine::GLTexture,struct Bengine::ColorRGBA8,bool,struct glm::detail::tvec4<float,0>)" (?init@Box@@QAEXPAVb2World@@U?$tvec2@M$0A@@detail@glm@@1UGLTexture@Bengine@@UColorRGBA8@7@_NU?$tvec4@M$0A@@45@@Z)". NinjaPlatformer PATH\Platformer\NinjaPlatformer\GameplayScreen.obj